# What is the reason behind using MOD equivalence notation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If the notation $$a \equiv b \pmod{n}$$ means `(a%n) = b`, then why don't we just use $(a\%b) = b$ as the notation instead of using $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ ?

Comment: It doesn't mean "$(a\% n)=b$".

Comment: Does $a\%n=b$ mean that $b$ is the remainder of the division of $a$ by $n$? This would be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I was expecting this reply because as of now this is so confusing to me. Some online videos say that this is $a \%n=b$ whereas some other texts say it is not. Though I am not yet getting any simple text explaining the real meaning of it and why do we call this as "equivalence" rather than equal.

Comment: While $17\neq 26$, nevertheless  $17 \equiv 26 \bmod 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $$a\equiv b \pmod n$$ you will find in most textbooks is
$$ n \mid (a-b) $$
that is, $a-b$ is an integer multiple of $n$.

If you have a well-behaved *binary* modulus operation this is equivalent to
$$ (a\bmod n) = (b\bmod n) $$
but this does not work really well as a definition, because the usual way to *define* the binary $\bmod$ is

> $x\bmod n$ means the number $y$ with $0\le y< n$ such that $x\equiv y\pmod n$.

so everything would be circular.

---

Note that this is *not* the same as
$$ a\mathbin{\%}n = b $$
and also not the same as
$$ a\mathbin{\%}n = b\mathbin{\%}n $$
if $\%$ is taken to be a remainder operator that works like `%` does in many programming languages -- because the way `%` works on *negative* arguments leads to wrong results; for example, such a definition would fail to make $(-4)\equiv 6\pmod{10}$ true.

---

One reason why that $\equiv$ notation is particularly useful is that it makes it easy to write an entire chain of congruences, such as:
$$ (a+kp)^2 \equiv a^2+(kp)^2+2akp \equiv a^2+p(k^2p+2a) \equiv a^2 \pmod p $$
Note that the $\pmod p$ morally applies to *each of the $\equiv$ signs*. It is not something that modifies the thing on the right of $\equiv$.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. I still wonder what you meant by "well-behaved binary modulus operation"?

Comment: @UtkalSinha: Basically one that behaves like the definition I quote for negative arguments, rather than one that behaves like the programming-language `%`.

Comment: got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually meaning of the equation is when you will divide 'a' by n and if reminder is what exactly if you divide 'b' by n then these two numbers are equivalent.

Comment: That's not necessarily true for negative $a$ and $b$, at least if "remainder" means what most people seem to take it to mean.

Comment: @HenningMakholm In number theory the remainder is taken to be between $0$ and the divisor, in which case this answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$a \%n = b$ means that $b$ is the remainder of the division of $a$ by $n$ (at least when $a,b,n$ are positive). But $a=b \pmod n$ does not mean that.

Rather, $a=b \pmod n$ means $a$ and $b$ have the *same* remainder upon division by $n$. For instance, $-1 = 15 \pmod 7$, but $15$ is certainly not the remainder of $-1$ on division by $7$. The notation $a \equiv_n b$ might make it more clear that this is an equivalence relation, not an operator mapping $(a,n)$ to $b$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd define $a\equiv b\;{mod}\; n$ as $n$ divides $a-b$. Then its easy to show that this relation is an equivalence/congruence relation on the ring of integers.